# assign null values to properties inside list

Tags: c#, list

I have declared list as below

```
 List<myList> mylist= new List<myList>();
```

Here is class for myList

```
internal class myList
{
    public int ID { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
}
```

Now when adding record inside list there are few null values coming from database in "Name" Field.

```
mylist.Add(new myList{ ID= (int) item["ID"], Name = item["Name"].ToString()});
```

I know i can add condition to check like

```
var Name ="";
if (item["Name"] !=null) {
      Name = item["Name"]
}
```

Then use variable `Name` while adding record to list

```
mylist.Add(new myList{ ID= (int) item["ID"], Name = Name});
```

is there any other better way?

Comment: You should definitly rename your class to the entity contained IN the list. I suppose something like `Person` should work

Comment: What is the type of `item["Name"]`? It doesn't help that we don't know what `item` is...

Comment: `(item["Name"] ?? "").ToString()` should do the trick, if item["Name"] returns null, it will set name to an empty string

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect you're looking for the [null-coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) here to provide a default value if the existing value is a null reference.

```
// Names changed to look more conventional
people.Add(new Person { Id = (int) item["ID"], Name = (string) item["Name"] ?? "" });
```

Note the use of a cast rather than a call to `ToString()` here - if you believe the execution-time type of a value will be a string reference, a cast is a much clearer indication of that, and it validates that expectation; if you end up with (say) a `DateTime` value for some reason, the cast will throw an exception rather than propagating bad data through your system.

Comment: i still get same error Object Reference not set to instance after using Your solution. Its my SharePoint list which has some null values

Comment: @Happy: And where is that exception occurring? It wouldn't happen in the line I've given unless `item` itself is `null`. Note that if you'd provided a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, I could have validated that all was well...

Comment: are you aware of SharePoint list ?

Comment: my mistake. Actually some other column was null too. Its working. Thanks